# Javascript removing unused positions

Tags: javascript, meta

I have 67 #pos but I only want the grab the specific ones listed here, how do I delete the others? In addition to that: How do I duplicate the #pos56 so that it works twice?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
titel ="C.M.I. 1";  
image = "1.png";
refreshtime = 60;
RefreshLink ="";
$('meta[name="viewport"]').replaceWith('<meta name="viewport" 
content="width=1906">');

</script>
<style type="text/css">
body{background:white;}
#values{width:1906px; height:864px;}
#pos35{position:absolute; top:306px; left:195px;}
#pos35{font-family: Arial; font-size: 27px; color: rgb(0,0,0); font-style: 
normal; font-weight: normal; text-align: left;}
#pos33{position:absolute; top:362px; left:195px;}
#pos33{font-family: Arial; font-size: 27px; color: rgb(0,0,0); font-style: 
normal; font-weight: normal; text-align: left;}
#pos34{position:absolute; top:306px; left:584px;}
#pos34{font-family: Arial; font-size: 27px; color: rgb(0,0,0); font-style: 
normal; font-weight: normal; text-align: left;}
#pos32{position:absolute; top:354px; left:582px;}
#pos32{font-family: Arial; font-size: 27px; color: rgb(0,0,0); font-style: 
normal; font-weight: normal; text-align: left;}
#pos56{position:absolute; top:317px; left:900px;}
#pos56{font-family: Arial; font-size: 27px; color: rgb(0,0,0); font-style: 
normal; font-weight: normal; text-align: left;}
#pos56{position:absolute; top:315px; left:1265px;}
#pos56{font-family: Arial; font-size: 27px; color: rgb(0,0,0); font-style: 
normal; font-weight: normal; text-align: left;}
#pos57{position:absolute; top:397px; left:1345px;}
#pos57{font-family: Arial; font-size: 27px; color: rgb(0,0,0); font-style: 
normal; font-weight: normal; text-align: left;}
</style>
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand your question at all...

Comment: The remaining #pos values show on the site but I dont want that.